# jQuery Read More container expanding issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to collapse and expand div based on click. Things with below code are working fine, but the container always stays expanded on page loads. So I want to do the reverse. When the page loads, it should be collapsed.

## jQuery

```
var showTotalChar = 200, showChar = "read more", hideChar = "less";
$('.review_item').each(function () {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showTotalChar) {
        var con = content.substr(0, showTotalChar);
        var hcon = content.substr(showTotalChar, content.length - showTotalChar);
        var txt = con + '<span class="morectnt"><span>' + hcon + '</span><span class="read-more sample"><a href="" class="clickme">' + hideChar + '</a></span>';
        $(this).html(txt);
    }
});
$(".clickme").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("sample")) {
        $(this).removeClass("sample");
        $(this).text(hideChar);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("sample");
        $(this).text(showChar);
    }
    console.log($(this).parent().prev());
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

## HTML/PHP

```
<?php
foreach ( $product[ 'review' ] as $review ): ?>
    <div class="greycont">
        <img src="<?php echo $review[ 'image_url' ] ?>"
             alt="<?php echo $review[ 'customer' ] ?>">
        <h2><?php echo $review[ 'review_heading' ] ?></h2>
        <div class="null"></div><!-- this div is just to avoid read more issue -->
        <div class="review_item">
            <?php //echo $review[ 'review_content' ] ?>
            <?php eWC_text_to_paragraph( $review[ 'review_content' ] ) ?>
        </div>
<!--                                <span class="read-more"><a href="#" class="clickme">read more...</a></span>-->
    </div><!-- end div class greycont -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Please help me to fix it!**

## Update

### Adding rendered HTML

```
<div class="greycont">
   <img src="http://localhost/swedencare/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/blogimg.jpg" alt="Elle Dicosta">
   <h2>This is an amazing product</h2>
   <div class="null"></div>
   <!-- this div is just to avoid read more issue -->
   <div class="review_item">
      <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they <span class="morectnt"><span>live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
         </span></span>
      </p>
      <p></p>
      <p>It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.</p>
      <p></p>
      <p>The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek.</p>
      <span class="read-more sample"><a href="" class="clickme">less</a></span>
   </div>
   <!--                                <span class="read-more"><a href="#" class="clickme">read more...</a></span>-->
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any working example which you can show? Also please inspect console for any errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am on my local end. I have checked console log before posting, and there is no error. The code is working fine but in a reverse way.  Means when page loads it always expanded but I want on load it should be collapsed.

Comment: Please share an example markup. PHP doesn't really help much here because an MCVE will require some example output.

Comment: css: `.review_item { display:none }` and please never call anything null

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for reply but it is hiding entire container and not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that you have a lot more code than you likely need.

Here is a simplified version of the setup I think you are aiming for:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.review_item p:nth-of-type(3)').slideToggle();
    $('.toggle').eq(1).toggle();

    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $('.review_item p:nth-of-type(3)').slideToggle();
        $('.toggle').toggle();
    });

});
```

```css
.toggle {
color: rgb(0,0,255);
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="review_item">
<p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.</p>

<p>It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.</p>

<p>The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek.</p>

<span class="toggle">Read More</span>
<span class="toggle">Read Less</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I am thankful to you for great suggestions and sample of code. I have one little issue in the code is my content doesn't have the same amount of paragraph for each review items. Can you guide me how can I write jQuery so it works regardless number of paragraphs?

Comment: Which paragraphs do you want to toggle? Is it always all of the paragraphs from the 3rd paragraph onwards?